# How can you get specific elements in jQuery.get "Data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have data (data.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.get("/computers/{{computer.id}}/live", function(data){
            console.log(data)
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

the problem is that "data" is the whole source code of the `"/computers/{{computer.id}}/live"` I want to get specific id in the html

> /computers/{{computer.id}}/live (HTML file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
            $('#id').load("")
        }, "{{timer}}");
      });
</script>
<div id="id">
<span class="badge badge-light"  id ="cpu">{{computer.cpu_usage_procentage}}</span>
<span class="badge badge-light"  id ="memory">{{computer.memory_usage_procentage}}</span>
</div>
```

How do I select the `cpu and memory` id and console.log their value (in `data.html` of course) or more specifically putting them in the `data.html` page

Comment: The API request returns HTML and you want to parse that HTML in order to pick out the values of specific IDs in the HTML? So essentially, a screen scrape?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno that does sound bad. So I need to create the id and the memory different URLs and just get their data separately?

Comment: You can update the endpoint to return HTML by default and JSON based on a query string parameter. Or just create a new one that returns the limited data you need for a less heavy response.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno should I send the JSON request using the "requests" module?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno is there a way that I could return JSON and render_template?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how your code is rendering the current HTML response. If the response is just loading onto the page, that's one thing. If you can returns two keys, where one is the HTML and the JSON, then just update your code to render the HTML key to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery default function to parse the html:

```js
 var html = `<div id="id">
<span class="badge badge-light"  id ="cpu">44%</span>
<span class="badge badge-light"  id ="memory">66%</span>
</div>`;
var parsed = $(html);

var cpuUsage = parsed.find("#cpu").text();
var memUsage = parsed.find("#memory").text();
console.log(`CPU usage ${cpuUsage} - Mem usage ${memUsage}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could also create an API in your server to provide the information in JSON format:

```
/computers/{{computer.id}}/livejson:

{
  cpuUsage: "{{computer.cpu_usage_procentage}}",
  memUsage: "{{computer.memory_usage_procentage}}"
}
```

And in the client:

```
 $.get("/computers/{{computer.id}}/livejson", function(json){
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(`CPU usage ${data.cpuUsage} - Mem usage ${data.memUsage}`);
 });
```

Comment: Yes but how do I do it so it will constantly get net data from the client? the cpu_usage_procentage changes every 5 seconds so I need to update it accordingly

Comment: That wasn't part of the question. If you can't find a way to do it, please post another question with what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: Can you please view my new question?